# Como organizar as condições do meu IF, ELSE

Tags: php, javascript, html

estou com dúvidas acerca de como devo declarar as condições do meu if, else.
Eu tenho uma página de login que faz uma verificação se o usuário é ADMIN, Usuário normal ou se é um Gerente.

O problema é que eu não estou conseguindo fazer a verificação do gerente funcionar junto com os outros dois, por conta da exigência de uma condição no else.

Vou mostrar primeiro o código como está e depois explicarei o que está dando problema.

Segue o trecho do código:

```
    switch ($_GET['opc']) {
    case 'login':
                    if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['login'])) $_POST['usuario'] = $_POST['login'];
        if (empty($_POST['usuario'])) campo_obrigatorio('usuario','Informe o usuário');
        if (empty($_POST['senha'])) campo_obrigatorio('senha','Informe a senha');
    
        ini_set('display_errors',0);
        ini_set('display_startup_erros',0);
        require_once("../class/class.administrador.php");
        $obj_admin = new administrador();
        $obj_admin->email = $_POST['usuario'];
        $obj_admin->senha = $_POST['senha'];
        $usuario_logado = $obj_admin->login(); 
        
        if (!$usuario_logado) {
            require_once("../class/class.clientes.php");
            $obj_cliente = new cliente();
            $obj_cliente->login = $_POST['usuario'];
            $obj_cliente->senha = $_POST['senha'];
            $usuario_logado = $obj_cliente->login();    
            
        }
        else if (!$usuario_logado){
            require_once("../class/class.corbanpj.php");
            $obj_corbanpj = new corbanpj();
            $obj_corbanpj->login = $_POST['usuario'];
            $obj_corbanpj->senha = $_POST['senha'];
            $usuario_logado = $obj_corbanpj->login();   
            if (!$usuario_logado) aviso_usuario('Usuário ou senha inválido(s)','erro');
            $tipo_usuario = 'CORBAN';
        }
        else {
            $tipo_usuario = $usuario_logado->tp_seg;
                            $nomeExibicao = explode(" ", $usuario_logado->nome);
            $usuario_logado->nome_responsavel = $nomeExibicao[0];
        }
```

Agora o problema é o seguinte:
Eu tenho a primeira verificação do usuário ADMIN que é feita sem nenhum if. Depois foi aberto um if que tem a condição caso o usuário não tenha logado, ele irá tentar abrir logar como cliente. Depois tentei colocar um else if com a mesma condição de caso não tenha logado para que então ele tente logar como gerente *corban*. Porém esse else if não está funcionando, por algum motivo a condição não está chegando nele, está indo direto pro else.
Não tem como eu tirar esse else pois ele é o passo seguinte após o login ocorrer, preciso saber que condição devo colocar no else if para que ele funcione.

PS: Se eu coloco o conteúdo do else if no if ele funciona perfeitamente e loga como gerente, porém preciso que os 3 funcione.

Se alguém conseguir me ajudar.

Favor: quem não puder ajudar não atrapalhe. o trecho do código que mostrei aqui é suficiente pra saber o motivo da condição não estar funcionando.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O problema é que você está fazendo um uso incorreto do bloco `if`.
Se uma das condições for aceita, o código dentro dela é executado e as outras condições não serão testadas.
Sendo assim, você não pode criar uma variável dentro de um bloco `if` e utilizá-la na verificação do bloco `else if`.
Creio que o código abaixo funcione para você;

```php
if (!$usuario_logado) {
    require_once("../class/class.clientes.php");
    $obj_cliente = new cliente();
    $obj_cliente->login = $_POST['usuario'];
    $obj_cliente->senha = $_POST['senha'];
    $usuario_logado = $obj_cliente->login();    
    
    if (!$usuario_logado) {
        require_once("../class/class.corbanpj.php");
        $obj_corbanpj = new corbanpj();
        $obj_corbanpj->login = $_POST['usuario'];
        $obj_corbanpj->senha = $_POST['senha'];
        $usuario_logado = $obj_corbanpj->login();   
        if (!$usuario_logado) aviso_usuario('Usuário ou senha inválido(s)','erro');
        $tipo_usuario = 'CORBAN';
    } else {
        $tipo_usuario = $usuario_logado->tp_seg;
                        $nomeExibicao = explode(" ", $usuario_logado->nome);
        $usuario_logado->nome_responsavel = $nomeExibicao[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Então, eu testei com o if ao invés do else if, porém ele não chega na condição.

Comment: Em qual condição você diz?